# extending wifi scan list to 2.3GHz and 10MHz width

Tags: linux, wifi, broadcom

How to extend wifi frequency scan list to be able to connect 2.3GHz or 2.5GHz access points?

And how to set channel width to 10MHz?

Arch Linux. Broadcom and Atheros drivers.

Comment: What exact type of card do you have?

Comment: @schaiba, now i have Broadcom BCM4313 pci and realtek rt2800 usb in hands. If those are not compatable I will try with another adapters.